# Test for presence of a property in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

In JavaScript we can test for the presence of a named property in an object using the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```javascript
var obj = { foo: 123, bar: 0 };
'foo' in obj; // => true
'bar' in obj; // => true, handy since "obj.bar" is falsey.
'gah' in obj; // => false
```

However, in CoffeeScript, the `in` operator is overloaded to perform an array search (presumably to prevent misuse of `for...in`), so we cannot use it as above.  Instead it seems like we must do a linear search for a named property in the object's list of keys:

```coffeescript
obj = { foo: 123, bar: 0 }
'foo' in Object.keys(obj) # true, but O(n) search instead of likely O(1).
```

#### Is there a better (more efficient, more concise) way to test for the existence of a named property in an object in CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use of :

```
obj ={foo:13}

(foo of obj) == true
```